# I need detailed explaination on why the pointer is pointing on a[2] because I don't understand and I thought it pointed to a[4]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, explain

I don't get why pshrt after the last line points at a[2], can someone explain in details please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main ()
{
    short a[10],*pshrt,shrt;
    char *pchar;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        a[i]=rand();
    //show
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    pchar = (char*)a;
    pshrt = (short*)(pchar+4);
    printf("%d",*pshrt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an array of `short`, which is probably two bytes on your system.  You increment a `char *` to that array by 4, so you move forward by 4 bytes.  Since the elements of the array are two bytes each, moving forward two bytes is the equivalent of moving forward two elements.

I'm not certain if your code is strictly legal as you are aliasing this `char *` with a `short *`.  It may be technically legal as the underlying element is effectively a `short`, but if you had incremented your `char *` by an odd amount and then cast that to a `short *`, now you're making an unaligned access.

Comment: It's legal. `char *` is a specific exception to the strict aliasing rules.

Comment: @user2357112 The hesitance I have is more going back *from* the `char *` to `short *`.  If you increment that `char *` in such a way that it does not meet `short` alignment requirements, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: (Come to think of it, strict aliasing probably isn't the right rule, since there's no value access through the `char *` here. I don't remember which rule or rules define the behavior involved here. Page 84, footnote 91 in the [N1256 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) talks about pointer arithmetic being equivalent to casting to `char *`, doing the math there, and casting back, but I don't think that's normative, and I don't know where to find all the separate normative pieces that combine to say this is okay.)

Comment: @user2357112  Yeah, that's why I left it as an uncertainty in the legality of it.  Suffice to say, I wouldn't ever want to commit code like this.  Even if it does happen to be technically legal; I'd rather not play with fire when there are better options.